# How to use ember-leaflet using ember-cli 2.6.2?

Tags: ember.js, leaflet, ember-data

So, I downloaded the addon https://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-leaflet/docs/container called ember-leaflet. The ember-cli version that I am using is `2.6.2`. Here's my code

```
  <LeafletMap lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom as |layers|>
    <layers.tile url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
  </LeafletMap>
```

The error that was shown on my console is `ember.debug.js:2925 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '|layers|' is not a valid attribute name.`

Any response is much appreciated

Comment: are you using https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill ?

Comment: hi @mistahenry I downloaded it but reproduce an error. I filed an issue to the addon itself. Started to get an error after I downloaded the addon

Comment: I see now  in the issue you opened that you are using `ember-cli` 2.12 but say here you are using `2.16`...what's more important is what version of `ember` you are using. I would update your issue with the value of `ember-source` in your `package.json`

Comment: Sorry, when I posted this question my ember-cli is `2.6.2`. @mistahenry Question is now updated.

Comment: The issue was updated as well.

Comment: Your ember-cli version is not the same thing as your `ember` version. Please check your package.json for `ember-source` or your `bower.json` (if you're still using) for your `ember`. This is the value that must be greater than 2.12, not the `ember-cli` value. `ember-cli` is just the build tool.

Comment: I think I learn something new from you today. Thank you

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so looking more closely at your problem, the html you have posted is not correct. It should be:

```
<LeafletMap @lat={{lat}} @lng={{lng}} @zoom={{zoom}} as |layers|>
  <layers.tile @url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
</LeafletMap>
```

In angle bracket invocation, you must use the `@` sign for passing in arguments to the component which you are not doing in your example.

But, let's take a step further back. Angle bracket component invocation was released in [3.4](https://blog.emberjs.com/2018/10/07/ember-3-4-released.html).There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill) available which you must install if you are before 3.4 and wish to use angle bracket invocation. At the end of the day, angle bracket invocation is mostly a syntactical difference(although don't get me wrong, there are improvements bundled in). It's not necessary that you use angle bracket invocation in your old `ember` app despite the leaflet documentation using said syntax. I have a 3.8 ember app in production that doesn't use a single angle bracket because I haven't had the time to convert.

You could just as easily be using this syntax and not bother trying to use the polyfill and wait to use angle bracket syntax until you move into 3.4+

```
{{#leaflet-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom as |layers|}}
  {{layers.tile url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}}
{{/leaflet-map}}
```

The ember guides have a [conversion guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/reference/syntax-conversion-guide/) which you can use as a reference point. It shouldn't be too hard to learn. I write maintain an Objective-C app and am constantly having to convert swift syntax to Objective C syntax when looking at guides, stackoverflow, etc. It's just the nature of maintenance and working with legacy :)

Comment: There was an error. I did removed the polyfill and use your suggestion but there was an error.

`Assertion Failed: The component helper cannot be used without a valid component name. You used "video-layer"`

But when I removed the code snippet it doesn't return an error.

Comment: Here's a comment from the owner of the addon as well https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-leaflet/issues/292

Comment: Try upgrading your leaflet version. Video layer was added in `3.0.17` but there was a [bug related to a missing re-export](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-leaflet/pull/203) that's probably causing this issue.